# Terraform AWS Resources getting modified even with same tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, tags

AWS resources are getting updated even when there is no change in resource configuration. As part of terraform plan tags are getting reapplied with same values.

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "sample_table" {
  name         = "sample_table_name"
  billing_mode = "PAY_PER_REQUEST"
  hash_key     = "sample_hash_key"
  range_key    = "sample_range_key"

  attribute {
    name = "sample_hash_key"
    type = "S"
  }
  attribute {
    name = "sample_range_key"
    type = "S"
  }
  tags = merge(
    local.common_tags,
    {
      "Name" = "sample_table_name"
    },
  )
}
```

Here `local.common_tags` is set of common tags defined in local section of main.tf file like below

```
locals {
  common_tags = {
    Source          = var.source_tag
    Owner           = var.owner_tag
    Contact         = var.contact_tag
  }
}
```

I'm performing terraform apply multiple times on same tf files without any change.
But the terraform says modifying the '***sample_table***' , below is the logs from terraform run.

```
# aws_dynamodb_table.sample_table will be updated in-place
 ~ resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "sample_table" {
       id                          = "sample_table_name"
       name                        = "sample_table_name"
     ~ tags                        = {
         + "Contact"         = "contact_me@example.com"
           "Name"            = "sample_table_name"
         + "Owner"           = "Owning_team"
         + "Source"          = "My_source"
       }
       # (10 unchanged attributes hidden)

       # (4 unchanged blocks hidden)
   }
```

You can see the tag defined at the resource level `"Name" = "sample_table_name"` not getting updated/modified, but the tags defined at locals are getting modified even though there isn't any change every time.

Terraform version and providers are as below.

```
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "4.63.0"
    }
}

terraform {
  required_version = "~> 1.4.5"
}
```

Comment: So it looks like it wants to add those common_tags every time. Did you verify they're being added properly in the AWS DynamoBD Console?
It's also interesting that you are adding variables in the locals block. I don't think that's necessary. Just for comparison sake, I would hardcode the common_tags values in the locals block & try applying terraform a couple times to see if there's changes in the results.

Comment: Hey @paulg, 
The tags are getting added in DDB that I verified.
Common tags has variable instead of hard coded values only because for multiple environment I need to configure different value.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was going through issue raised in github [default_tags always shows an update](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/18311), even though my issue isn't exactly similar, in one of the comment I saw it might be because of using both common tags like I used above, in addition to `default_tags` defined at `provoder.tf` file. So I just removed the common flag for now and handled everything in default flag. That is working for me as of now.